# ubuntu 13,10 problem

Tags: software-installation, 13.10

i just have a problem on ubuntu.
when i go to ubuntu Software Center, i can not download any application although i can surf the internet. when i download an app it stops at 10% and then an message appears <1. please help. i am from greece and my computer does not support ubuntu 14,04+.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 13.10 is a really bad thing, it is not supported for about 2 years now. It is not as bad as using Windows XP but spending a minimum amount of money to upgrade to a better Computer would be the best. I think you can't install any software because your OS is just too old. AND Ubuntu Software Center is longer used. Try installing `Synaptic` from the terminal: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install  synaptic && sudo synaptic` If you can install and start that you are able to install packages

Comment: You may want to ask a question on the specific issue you encounter with a supported Ubuntu release. Voting to close this for now as per the [faq].

Comment: 13.10 went End-Of-Life ages ago, to continue receiving updates and support please upgrade to a supported release (currently 12.04, 14.04 and 16.04). The repositories for EOL releases are archived so unless you add them you won't be able to install anything, but I would advise that you upgrade/downgrade to a supported release as the repositories have not been updated since the release went EOL.

Comment: besides that: if Unity does not work find an alternative. xUbuntu or lUbuntu.

Comment: Your computer can support 14.04+, it just (possibly) can't support it running Unity. You could try using Lubuntu or Ubuntu MATE instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your situation, the only answer I can give you, is to downgrade your Ubuntu to the **12.04 LTS** version. In my opinion, there are several advantages in doing so.

- First of all, 12.04 is obviously, older than 13.10, so, at least theoretically, it should put less pressure on your device's resources.
- Secondly, 12.04 is a LTS, which means that it is more stable than any *.10 distro. Besides of that, 13.10 is no longer supported, while 12.04 is. And is in your own interest to run a distro which is still supported so that you can be on the safe side.
- And, finally, if, insted of the "pure" Ubuntu, you'll choose Xubuntu or Lubuntu, then the above mentioned pressure on your PC's resources will be diminished even more.

So, as a conclusion, you should install **Xubuntu 12.04 LTS** or **Lubuntu 12.04 LTS**. If you don't know which one of them you like, then create a live stick with each one of them and play a while so that you can get accustomed.

I can assure you, I run a 12.04 on one of devices and I don't miss anything. On another device, I have a 16.04 preinstalled. Well, I can tell you that some apps are not yet adapted for this version, so I have to find others. Not a very pleasing situation.

But all in all, there is not much difference. You can use a **12.04** without any problems.

Comment: Thank you! your answer was very helpful!!!!! i will try to install it right now!!!!